Ubuntu 24.04 cannot find bluetooth devices
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 to a ThinkPad e470 running an intel i7 with 8 gig ram.  This is a full install.  When I run systemctl-status-bluetooth this appears -

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-11-17 15:33:35 CST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1908 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9317)
     Memory: 2.1M (peak: 2.6M)
        CPU: 132ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1908 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Which strikes me as good sign.  Yet I still cannot find my earbuds when scanning for devices.  Worse, my attempt to install Bluez from the App Center remains with a grayed out "open" button.  I had the same issues on a Dell XPS running 23.04.  Can Ubuntu easily and reliably run Bluetooth fresh from install?

I thought it might help to note the devices that do appear all call for ID approval.  My girlfriend's macbook pro for example appears, and I can approve it with a code that then appears on the macbook pro.  It also works for our Levoit Series 300 air filter, which I haven't even established yet in Google Assistant, and the living room Samsung TV.  Neither of these latter devices need be on to appear in Bluman.

You can check to see if you have the necessary packages installed
From a terminal, [code] dpkg -l blue* [/code]
Bluetooth works on my machines. These three are what I have installed on Xubuntu 22.04.5 LTS.
Install from terminal,
[code] sudo apt install bluez blueman bluez-obexd [/code]

Thanks for your response Hugh!  I followed your instructions and installed blueman.  The application front end revealed a number of devices, only one of which I recognized by name.  All the while my Sony SRS-XB13 speaker was right next to me, waiting to pair.  I should also add the command bluez.bluetoothctl brought back this response -  process 7516: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection != NULL" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2830. This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

I also have a SRS-XB13; although, lately I have been using a bluetooth headset Tayogo, S2.  Afraid I can not help with the error messages.
